# Which is the better VLC Portable version?

Tags: vlc-media-player, portable-apps

VLC 7zip and Zip packages are [available](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) and also [VLC Portable from PortableApps site](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable). Which is better for not leaving traces when run from my USB drive? Are the packages portable versions?

Comment: What? Do you even know what a .zip file is?

Comment: @MichaelK: Seems you and others in a hurry to close this have completely missed what he's trying to ask here. The 7z/ZIP files do not contain the EXE installer. They actually contain the individual (post-install) files i.e. [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NKUwq.png). What the OP seems to want to know is, are these versions portable or should he use the one from the other site not affiliated with VLC?

Comment: @Karan well, in that case it would have been nice from him to ask that. Specific information about the problem may help solving it. Also the "Which is better for not leaving traces when run from my USB drive?" question seems pretty out of place and questionable.

Comment: @MichaelK: I found it neither off-topic nor questionable. I tend not to simply assume that something's amiss or people are doing something illegal just because they want to hide their tracks etc. After all, that would imply that questions about clearing browser history, or retrieving the OS product key, or clearing the admin password because someone says they forgot it and so on are all "questionable" as well, yet we have plenty of those on the site. Almost anything can be turned around and looked at suspiciously that way, and if we did that most questions would get closed right away.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the non-installer versions are *not* truly portable, so I recommend you use the one packaged by the PortableApps guys that uses their own wrapper to prevent system access (in terms of writing files/settings to AppData, the registry and other locations). (Of course, Windows will always record traces of program usage in the registry.)